# Usefulness of the comma operator in comparisons

Tags: javascript

I saw a comparison like the following in a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656050/javascript-unexpected-outcome-of-character-removal-code):

`(pNum != ('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))`

The OP has been trying to check if a **number falls in a certain range** but this code is inaccurate as it will always compare with right most value inside the brace(i.e. 9)
This means when `pNum = 2` the comparison will return `true` and not `false` as was expected by OP who was expecting it to work like `inArray` or `in`.

My question is whether this sort of comparison is going to be useful in any real case in any scenario?

Comment: `var arr = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']; return arr.includes(pNum);`

Comment: @gurvinder372 that wasnt the question ;)

Comment: @Jamiec oh, anyways was only confirming through a comment.

Comment: @Jamiec this question has nothing in common with the duplicate

Comment: @pwolaq you sure? ref: "My question is whether this sort of comparison is going to be useful "

Comment: @Jamiec ok, you are right, my bad :)

Comment: The title does not match the body,

Comment: The expression does not make any sense. Please point to the question / answer where you have seen this

Comment: @smnbbrv its at the bottom of the code here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656050/javascript-unexpected-outcome-of-character-removal-code

Comment: @Jamiec Possibly related not duplicate.

Comment: @techie_28 It is literally the same question. With the same answer.

Comment: @Jamiec and perhaps you are the one downvoting?

Comment: well okay,Please tell me how to accept that "it is the duplicate of that question as an answer"?

Comment: this is a closer possible duplicate in the context of the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561043/what-does-a-comma-do-in-javascript-expressions

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether this sort of comparison is going to be useful in any real case in any scenario?

No. As you observe, the comparison only compares the last item inside the bracket. So all it can accomplish is to confuse the reader.

If you intend to compare a variable with a set of values, you could use [`array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) or `array#indexOf >= 0`. Something like:

```js
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].includes('2'));
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].includes('6'));
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].includes('9'));

// IE 
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].indexOf('2') >= 0);
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].indexOf('6') >= 0);
console.log(['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'].indexOf('9') >= 0);
```